# Calling Flash Magic from command line with parentheses in path

Tags: command-line, arm, embedded, microprocessors

I need to program my microcontroller via Flash Magic command line.

Command is:

```
COM(6, 115200)
DEVICE(LPC2368, 4.000000, 0) 
HARDWARE(BOOTEXEC, 50, 100) 
ERASE(DEVICE, PROTECTISP) 
HEXFILE(C:\Program Files (x86)\myfile.hex, NOCHECKSUMS, NOFILL, PROTECTISP).
```

When using any different path without parentheses, this goes perfectly well.
But when "(x86)" is involved I get an error:

> ERROR: Invalid parameters for HEXFILE directive: HEXFILE(C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)

I tried surrounding the path with quotes or double quotes but I get the same error.

Does anyone know how to **correctly pass a path argument with parentheses**?

Comment: You mean to put double quotes around the path? I already tried that, and I get the same error.    I cannot change the path, the file I need is in Program Files (x86)!

Comment: Try: C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\myfile.hex (just writing a '\ ' instead of a whitespace)

Comment: It is not about the path containing "(x86)", but rather one containing spaces, since space is an argument delimiter in Windows' command lines. It is reporting that both Files" and "(x86)" are invalid parameters.  This is a general question about how to use a computer rather then programming, so probably off topic.  Use : `HEXFILE("C:\Program Files (x86)\myfile.hex", NOCHECKSUMS, NOFILL, PROTECTISP)`.

Comment: @AlexF : Hard to recommend because of ambiguity between "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" on 64 bit Windows (and for that matter any other folder on the C: drive system that may start "Progra".  Better to add  "C:\Program Files (x86)\" the `PATH` environment variable perhaps?  Though it begs the question of why the program was installed in the root of "Program Files (x86)"  - presumably put there manually - in which case move it to a path without spaces?

Comment: Thank you @Clifford, but I think I know how to use a computer. If you read the question, you will discover that I tried surrounding the argument with quotes and double quotes, but it does not work. Moreover, I am fairly sure that the problem is with the parentheses and not the spaces, because with the path "C:\Program Files\..." (that contains a space as well!) the command works perfectly.

Comment: @danlor In WIndows `\` is a path directory delimiter.

Comment: You may have mentioned it, but you did not show it.  Show explicitly all the things that _don't work_ and the resulting error messages  _and_ the thing that does work, so we can see exactly what is going on.  The error message you posted is clearly objecting to "Files" before "(x86)" so the evidence presented fits my hypothesis.

Comment: @AlexF : good spot - makes sense since `(' and ')' are already delimiters in the FlashMagic command file syntax.

Comment: @Clifford Well, the sentence "When using any different path without parentheses, this goes perfectly well" seemed pretty clear to me. I'll try to be more precise the next time, thank you.

Comment: I've got to ask, what business has `myfile.hex` being in an OS reserved path for Windows program installations in any case?  Better to fix the build system that placed it there than carry on polluting that folder.

Comment: @AlexF I didn't find anything on the forum, I must have missed that post! I will look there, thank you very much.

Comment: Fair enough, but it is nice to _see_ all the same evidence you can see to come to the same _informed_ opinion.

Comment: @Clifford The file I need is installed in Program Files (x86) by an older software of my company, not much to do about that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192946/discussion-between-clifford-and-farfetched).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same problem:

there is no workaround with versions <12 of Flash Magic, but fortunately version 12 resolves this issue.